# post base64 string within url using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to post some images to server, which images are encoded in base64 string. i'm using Alamofire to post images and in my case, there are no parameter in my post method and all are in url.
here is how i encode images to base64 string:

```
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(data)! as NSData
let strBase64:String = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
self.pictures[1] = strBase64
```

and here's my alamofire usage:

```
let header : HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]
url = "myUrl"
Alamofire.request(url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)! , method: .post, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .methodDependent) , headers : header)
```

the service on server is `FormUrlEncoded` type. how can I send images, i'm using swift as my programming language.